# Установление соединения между двумя телефонами

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, у меня есть цель: объединить два телефона (подключенных не к одной сети) для передачи строковых значений. Представляю я это примерно так: есть глобальный ip, локальный ip, порт. Зная эти значения, устанавливается соединение, примерно как сокеты. Работаю в Андроид Студио. Подскажите, как это можно реализовать и в каком направлении вообще двигаться?

Comment: А в чём проблема? Что сделано, что не получается? Если есть внешний ip у обоих устройств, то проблем быть не должно.

Comment: В сторону какой технологии надо смотреть?